# Jms-message-driven channel adaper not rolling back the transaction

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-transactions

I am breaking my head against the wall since I do not have a clue of why the transactions are not rolling back.

I am using spring integration in my project and my `applicationContext.xml` looks like below:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.jms.spring.integration.*"></context:component-scan>

<tx:annotation-driven/>

<int:poller default="true" id="poller" fixed-delay="500"></int:poller>

<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
    channel="processEmpChannel" destination-name="com.test.inputqueue" acknowledge="transacted" connection-factory="targetConnectionFactory"/>

<bean id="targetConnectionFactory"  class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="springExample" class="com.jms.spring.integration.SpringIntegrationJmsExample">
</bean>

<int:service-activator input-channel="processEmpChannel"
    ref="springExample" method="handleClient">
   <int:poller ref="poller"></int:poller>
</int:service-activator>
```

My java file looks like this:

```
package com.jms.spring.integration;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

public class SpringIntegrationJmsExample {
    @Transactional
    public void handleClient(String str){
        System.out.println("handleClient");
        throw new RuntimeException("Throwing some runtime exception....");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    }
}
```

When I post the message on the queue, I see the exception but the message in the queue is consumed. The transaction is not rolling back and the message is not put back in the queue. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `processEmpChannel` is a QueueChannel; the transaction commits as soon as the message is put in the channel queue (before it is processed by the service).

You need to use `DirectChannel`s for transactions to work as expected so the service activator is run on the listener container thread (remove the poller).

See [Message Channels](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html) and [Transaction Support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/transactions.html).

Comment: Thanks. That worked like a charm. However, the AMQ will try to deliver 8 times and then the message is consumed. How do configure to put the message which failed even after 8 attempts in a dead queue?

Comment: That's configured on the broker; it's not part of the JMS spec; search the AMQ docs.